# transpose different matrices in parallel

Tags: c++, cuda

I have like 3 different size of matrices and want to transpose them parallel.

Firstly I put these in a 2D array using malloc and then use cudaMalloc to transfer array from host(h_B) to device (d_B).

Using threadIdx to find each address of matrix in the array. The cublas function is used.
Here are my code.

The code can be compiled but I cannot get result.  It seems that in global function `float *A = new float[m*n]` is not a good way.

Dose anyone have ideas of this?
Thanks so much!

```
/* Includes, system */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

/* Includes, cuda */
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

/* Includes, cuda helper functions */
#include <helper_cuda.h>

__global__ void transposeCublasSgeam(int *M_A, int *N_A, float *ptrA, float *ptrC, const int N, int *address)
{
    cublasHandle_t cnpHandle;
    cublasStatus_t status = cublasCreate(&cnpHandle);

    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        return;
    }

    const float d_alpha = 1.0f;
    const float d_beta = 0.0f;
    int idx = threadIdx.x;
    if(idx<N){
      int m = M_A[idx]; //A_row
      int n = N_A[idx]; //A_col
      float *A = new float[m*n]; 
      float *C = new float[m*n];
      A = ptrA+address[idx];
      C = ptrC+address[idx];
      cublasSgeam(cnpHandle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_T, m, n, &d_alpha, (const float*)A, n, &d_beta, (const float *)A, n, C, m);
      delete[] A;
      delete[] C;
    }
     cublasDestroy(cnpHandle);

}

int main()
{

    const int N = 3;
    int M_B[N] = { 2,3,2 }; //row number of matrices 
    int N_B[N] = { 3,2,4 }; //col number of matrices 

    float a[6] = { 1,2,3,
                  4,5,6 };
    float b[6] = { 1,2,
                 3,4,
                 5,6};
    float c[8] = { 1,2,3,1,
                  2,3,4,5 };

    float **h_B = (float**)malloc(N * sizeof(float*));
    float **h_BT = (float**)malloc(N * sizeof(float*));

    h_B[0] = a, h_BT[0] = a;
    h_B[1] = b, h_BT[1] = b;
    h_B[2] = c, h_BT[2] = c;

    int NUM_B = 20; // total number of elements
    int address[] = {0,6,12}; 

    float *d_B, *d_BT;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, NUM_B * sizeof(float)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_BT, NUM_B * sizeof(float)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_B, NUM_B * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_BT, h_BT, NUM_B * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    transposeCublasSgeam<<<1,N>>>(M_B, N_B, d_B,d_BT, N,address); 

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_BT, d_BT, NUM_B * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_BT);
    delete[] h_B;
    delete[] h_BT;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are `N` and `M` allways known at compiletime? You could make your kernel a template and use arrays of fixed size.

Comment: You change `A` to point somewhere else and then call `delete`. This is an error even in host code.

Comment: I am not familiar with cublas, but are the functions really meant to be called from an kernel? Otherwise you might look into `cublasSetStream`.

Comment: The cublas function can be called from the device.  I think the point is how to get the corresponding data of matrix from the array. And malloc A and C in device maybe be wrong?

Comment: Seems your are right and it is possible: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations

Comment: I doubt that the line `A = prtA +address[x]` does what you want. This changes the pointer not the value, leaving no way to access the allocated memory.

Comment: It changes the pointer to point the another matrix in the array. For example, the first matrix has 6 elements, the pointer is ptrA[0]. To second data of matrix,  the pointer is  ptrA+6.

Comment: In newer CUDA versions, the cublas function cannot be called from device code.  That functionality (cublas from device code) was deprecated and is now removed.  It is not supported in CUDA 10.  So while you may be able to get this working in some fashion, it will not be supportable in newer versions of CUDA.

Comment: I use cuda 8, and I run the simpleDevLibCUBLAS, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of errors in your code.  I will probably miss some in my description.

1. Note that this cublas-in-device-code functionality is no longer available in newer CUDA versions.
2. Every pointer that is passed to device code needs an allocation with `cudaMalloc`.  You had done `cudaMalloc` for a few pointers, but not all of them.
3. You're confused about pointers and arrays of pointers.  I won't be able to sort all of that out for you.  Your kernel design really doesn't need the complexity of using arrays of pointers.  So I've removed all that.
4. In CUDA dynamic parallelism (CDP), pointers to the local address space cannot be passed to child kernels. You can't use alpha and beta in the local address space, and pass pointers to those to CUBLAS in CDP.
5. To do a pure transpose, study [the CUBLAS Sgeam documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-geam) for the recommended parameters to use.

I believe there were other things I fixed.  Please study this example:

```
$ cat t1433.cu
/* Includes, system */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

/* Includes, cuda */
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

/* Includes, cuda helper functions */
#include <helper_cuda.h>

__global__ void transposeCublasSgeam(int *M_A, int *N_A, float *ptrA, float *ptrC, const int N, int *address)
{
    cublasHandle_t cnpHandle;
    cublasStatus_t status = cublasCreate(&cnpHandle);

    if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("thread: %d, error1: %d\n", threadIdx.x, (int)status);
        return;
    }

    float *d_alpha =  new float; // a pointer to device-heap, not local memory
    *d_alpha = 1.0f;
    float *d_beta  = new float;
    *d_beta = 0.0f;
    int idx = threadIdx.x;
    if(idx<N){
      int m = M_A[idx]; //A_row
      int n = N_A[idx]; //A_col
      status = cublasSgeam(cnpHandle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, n, d_alpha, ptrA+address[idx], n, d_beta, ptrC+address[idx], m, ptrC+address[idx], m);
      if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
      {
        printf("thread: %d, error2: %d\n", threadIdx.x, (int)status);
        return;
      }
    }
     cublasDestroy(cnpHandle);

}

int main()
{

    const int N = 3;
    int M_B[N] = { 2,3,2 }; //row number of matrices
    int N_B[N] = { 3,2,4 }; //col number of matrices

    float a[6] = { 1,2,3,
                  4,5,6 };
    float b[6] = { 1,2,
                 3,4,
                 5,6};
    float c[8] = { 1,2,3,1,
                  2,3,4,5 };
    float *h_Bdata  = (float *)malloc(sizeof(a)+sizeof(b)+sizeof(c));
    float *h_BTdata = (float *)malloc(sizeof(a)+sizeof(b)+sizeof(c));
    memcpy(h_Bdata, a, sizeof(a));
    memcpy(h_Bdata+(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])), b, sizeof(b));
    memcpy(h_Bdata+(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))+(sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0])), c, sizeof(c));

    int NUM_B = 20; // total number of elements
    int address[] = {0,6,12};
    int *d_address;
    cudaMalloc(&d_address, sizeof(address));
    cudaMemcpy(d_address, address, sizeof(address), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    int *d_M_B, *d_N_B;
    cudaMalloc(&d_M_B, sizeof(M_B));
    cudaMalloc(&d_N_B, sizeof(N_B));
    cudaMemcpy(d_M_B, M_B, sizeof(M_B), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_N_B, N_B, sizeof(N_B), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    float *d_B, *d_BT;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, NUM_B * sizeof(float)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&d_BT, NUM_B * sizeof(float)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_B, h_Bdata, NUM_B * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    transposeCublasSgeam<<<1,N>>>(d_M_B, d_N_B, d_B,d_BT, N,d_address);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(h_BTdata, d_BT, NUM_B * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    std::cout << "B , BT" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_B; i++){
      std::cout << h_Bdata[i]  << " , " << h_BTdata[i] << std::endl;}
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_BT);

    return 0;
}
$ /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples/common/inc  t1433.cu -rdc=true -lcublas_device -lcudadevrt -arch=sm_35 -o t1433
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="3" cuda-memcheck ./t1433
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
B , BT
1 , 1
2 , 4
3 , 2
4 , 5
5 , 3
6 , 6
1 , 1
2 , 3
3 , 5
4 , 2
5 , 4
6 , 6
1 , 1
2 , 2
3 , 2
1 , 3
2 , 3
3 , 4
4 , 1
5 , 5
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I run it successfully. I still confused that only constant values don't  need to be passed to device?

Comment: You'll need to get a really crisp understanding of what pass by value means in the C programming language. All kernel parameters are pass by value. Dereferencing any pointer must result in a proper device address.

Comment: sorry, wrong expression. I mean that only constant value can directly be passed to device and others need  an allocation with cudaMalloc?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant also.  All kernel parameters are pass-by-value.  For a scalar quantity, pass-by-value works just fine.  For a pointer quantity, the pointer *value* (i.e. address) will get passed by value.  When you dereference that pointer (i.e. use the address to retrieve a value) that *address* had better point to device memory. Therefore **any time you pass a pointer to the device, that pointer had better point to device memory**.  This is a fundamental CUDA concept.  You cannot dereference device pointers in host code, or host pointers in device code.

Comment: But you are not dereferencing a scalar quantity.  So pass-by-value works just fine there, and you get to use the quantity directly in device code.  You'll really need to understand pointers and pass-by-value better, and these are both C programming concepts, not unique or specific to CUDA.